# Flask runs out of virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, flask-restful

I was working in virtual environment but I removed the virtual environment folder in purpose. But  I still can run flask restful application as below, while new empty virtual environment(there are no libraries in site packages but even application works like old virtual environment) is active.

```
flask run
```

I thought it should have been failed and complaining like:

> no module named flask

, because I removed the old proper virtual environment and installed new one then activated it.

And here is the point, when I try the run the main script as below

```
python3 app.py
```

It complains as expected:

> no module named flask

It seems that when I run with `flask run` it is not using virtual environment even virtual environment is active. Because of this reason I can't test my application with other python versions and can't test if requirements are installed and run in new other virtual environments. I couldn't understand this behavior of the flask for any help I appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on vscode, running on Ubuntu 22, the import flask line is underlined(yellow squiggly line) however, python3 is running on 3.10.6 on venv, and it runs well on the browser, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out what is going on there.

Flask creates a directory named local  in home and moved system's interpreter and dependencies there included by flask application that I wrote.

Then it deploys the application from there when run with `flask run`. So that means my flask app was not running with virtual environment as we guess.

So in that case I recreated my virtual environment and after installing dependencies I run  with `python3 app.py`. Now it seems that it uses the virtual environment dependencies and interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

You may have `Flask` globally installed.

```
pip list | grep flask
```

You can remove that:

```
pip uninstall flask
```

or

Create `virtualenv` with `--no-site-packages` option:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
or 
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```