# ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' . even though it did not imported it

Tags: flask, flask-login

```
from flask import Flask,request , render_template , redirect , url_for
from flask_login import LoginManager , UserMixin , login_user , login_required , logout_user , current_user 
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
```

i am trying to make a login and signup page using flask. but its giving error that

```
prakash@prakash-laptop:~/Desktop/flask/auth_$ python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prakash/Desktop/flask/auth_/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import _app_ctx_stack, current_app
ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (/home/prakash/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
```

i had not imported " _app_ctx_stack"  then also its showing error

i tried to reinstall flask_login and flask

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340344/cannot-use-module-aioflaskpython-importerror-cannot-import-name-app-ctx-st

Comment: i had tried every solution available in stackoverflow. even i downgraded flask. nothing woked.(actuall i get some other weird error after downgrading flask)

Comment: I recommend that you try running the same project on another computer to check whether the issue lies with a defective installation, Python, or the computer itself.

Comment: i solved the issue. " from flask_mysqldb import MySQL"  is a bad way to use it. and then later i studied about sqlalchemy . so it solved my problem. thank u so much for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly in flask_mysqldb . Perhaps the module has errors? Its not a very big project, and might have fallen out of support. Flask's most recent version was on feb 4th of 2024. flask_mysqldb was on oct 5th 2023. I highly suggest using mysql-connector-python instead.

Edit:
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1856
and https://github.com/fedora-copr/flask-whooshee/issues/71
both tell us that '_app_ctx_stack' has been deprecated. It is still in use in flask_mysqldb though. This seems to further reinforce my point above

> From the Flask changelog:
>
> The app and request contexts are managed using Python context vars
> directly rather than Werkzeug’s LocalStack. This should result in
> better performance and memory use.
> [#4682](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4682)
>
> ```
> Extension maintainers, be aware that _app_ctx_stack.top and _request_ctx_stack.top
> are deprecated. Store data on g instead using a unique prefix, like g._extension_name_attr.
> ```

Comment: i used flask_mysql_connector after that . but then now its giving some error like , "ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' ". is there any better way to connect with mysql ? " mysql-connector-python" is also not working

Comment: are you sure mysql-connector-python is not working? Could you create a gist or a codepen with the code? Ive used it forever and it always worked..

Comment: yup that was not working. idk may i dont know how to use it .  but then i lerned about sqlalchemy and now my life is better :)